# SQL: Finding a column entry given another column entry in the same row

Tags: mysql, database, select, post

I'm wondering how I can find a column entry given another column entry in the same row? To clarify using my table:

```
|id|name|age|
-------------
|0 |john|43 |
|1 |jake|23 |
|2 |jess|25 |
```

I would like to set up a query that returns the 'id' given a 'name'. For example, if I give the query (or function if I need that) the name 'jake' I would like to return (and store in a variable) the id '1'. I'd greatly appreciate the help :-) Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE name='jake'`

Comment: We love to help, but sometimes you just have to get down and dirty with the manual / tutiorials / a decent book, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id into @data from table_name where name='john'
```

Comment: Welcome...I did the same but you rejected earlier :P

Answer (score 0):

Simply write:

```
select id INTO @myvar from mytable where name='jake'
```